# React JS - Store radio button values into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, radio-button

I need some help regarding storing radio button checked values into an array, I tried but I could'nt make anything work, here is my code
so I want to transfer and store the checked radio buttons into an array 
I don't know what to do ..

My code:

```
class Question extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { val: "" };
    this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this);
  }
  //this.setState = {answers: {}};
  onInput(e) {
    this.setState({ val: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.data);
  }
  render() {
    var that = this; // Funny way to be able to access this from inside our iterator() function below.
    var iterator = this.props.questionChoices.map((choice, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label className="container">
            <input
              className="input"
              key={i}
              type={that.props.questionType}
              name={that.props.questionID}
              value={choice}
              onChange={that.onInput}
            />
            &nbsp; {choice}
            <span className="checkmark" />
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="form">
          <Paper zDepth={1}>
            <div className="h3">
              <h3 className="h3outter">
                {this.props.questionID} - {this.props.questionText}
              </h3>
              <p className="h3inner">{iterator}</p>
            </div>
          </Paper>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't immediately check state after changing it with `setState` as `setState` is an async process. `setState` does have a callback you can use, however.

Comment: Can you add an example of `questionChoices` to your question?

Comment: {
    "questionID": 3,
    "questionType": "radio",
    "questionText": "L'unité du courant électrique est",
    "choices": ["L’Ampère", "Le Volt", "Le Watt"],
    "answer": "L’Ampère"
  },

Comment: sorry for the layout, this is the begining of the questions.json so the choices are in there

Comment: I still don't get your problem. One thing I noticed is that `this.setState({val: e.target.value});` will be `this.setState({val: e.target.checked});`

Comment: i idea is that this react app , is a set of questions right , so there are 2/3 radio buttons as answers for each question, all i want is to get the values selected (of the radio button of course) and store them in an array.

Comment: Ok .. so answerId and the selection?

Comment: well yea the answer is the selected radio ,, validation will come later

Comment: yes exactly , but there is a problem , if you select a radio, its saved in an array and thats what i want exaclty,,,the problem is when selecting another radio in the same question the array will have two values

Comment: I've updated my answer, @NizarJailane, to resolve that problem.

Comment: change your state val from string to an array. like this.state = { val: [] } and in onInput function push the checked value to the array like onInput(e) {
    this.setState({ val: e.target.checked });
  } so what will happen here whenever onInput triggered value will store into val array

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I fiddled around with your code a little bit and came up with this. In the `render` it iterates over the questions but also (the bit you were missing) iterates over the radio button choices too.

The important part is in `onInput` where we take the existing state and add the new radio button value to it. And if the question has already been answered we remove the exising answer, and replace it with the new one.

```
class Question extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { values: [] };
    this.onInput = this.onInput.bind(this);
    this.buildRadioButtons = this.buildRadioButtons.bind(this);
  }

  onInput(e) {
    const id = e.target.name;
    const answer = { id, answer: e.target.value };
    let answers;
    if (this.state.answers.some(answer => answer.id === id)) {
      answers = [...this.state.answers.filter(answer => answer.id !== id), answer];
    } else {
      answers = [...this.state.answers, answer];
    }
    this.setState({ answers }, () => console.log(this.state.answers));
  }

  buildRadioButtons(arr, type, id) {
    return arr.map((choice, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <input
          type={type}
          name={id}
          value={choice}
          onChange={this.onInput}
        />          
        <label>{choice}</label>
      </div>
     )
  })
 }

  render() {
    var iterator = this.props.questionChoices.map((question, i) => {
      const { choices, questionType, questionID, questionText } = question;
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <h3>{questionText}</h3>
          {this.buildRadioButtons(choices, questionType, questionID)}
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="form">
          <div >
            <div className="h3">
              {iterator}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const questionChoices = [
  { "questionID": 3, "questionType": "radio", "questionText": "L'unité du courant électrique est", "choices": ["L’Ampère", "Le Volt", "Le Watt"], "answer": "L’Ampère" },
    { "questionID": 2, "questionType": "radio", "questionText": "What is your name?", "choices": ["Dave", "Nizar", "Bob"], "answer": "Nizar" }
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Question questionChoices={questionChoices} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**[Here's a working copy](https://jsfiddle.net/1L8xb3r5/8/)**

Comment: in your working copy,  label on click does not work to select the radio